Derived $\infty$-category of quasi-coherent sheaves on schemes
Let $X$ be a scheme. On the one hand, we have the derived $\infty$-category constructed from the abelian category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$. On the other hand, we can define the stable $\infty$-category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$ as $\varprojlim_{Spec(A)\to X}\mathcal D(A)$. Is there an obvious way to see the equivalence of the two constructions?

This equivalence seems unlikely without quasicompactness assumption; if I'm not mistaken, you'll get two different categories for infinite disjoint union of points.

See Remark 5.32 of https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.14594 for a discussion of related results. Quasi-compact and semi-separated are the restrictions to impose.
